# Generating Dashboard Reports in Thingsboard: Backend vs. Frontend Approach

Tags: report, thingsboard

I am currently working on generating reports from a dashboard in Thingsboard. Initially, I attempted to create reports from the frontend, but encountered issues with missing images. Now, I'm considering generating these reports from the backend.

I'm seeking advice and ideas on how to efficiently generate reports, whether from the backend or frontend, and ensure that the images are correctly displayed?